# Changing or removing the carrier name on the iOS simulator using xcrun simctl status_bar

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcrun

As of iOS 13, [SimulatorStatusMagic](https://github.com/shinydevelopment/SimulatorStatusMagic) no longer works, but happily Apple have provided a first-party solution through `simctl status_bar`.

However I can't find any way to remove or change the "Carrier" text:

[image: iOS 13 Status Bar]

Setting `--cellularMode notSupported` removes it, but it also removes the cellular bars.

Is there any way to reproduce the previous functionality of SimulatorStatusMagic and remove or change just the carrier name?

**Edit:** Xcode 11.4 includes a new parameter to set the operator name, though it doesn't seem to work. The documentation provides the following:

```
    --operatorName <string>
         Set the cellular operator/carrier name. Use '' for the empty string.
```

Comment: Yes, that's missing, even though Apple hides it in its own screenshots on the App Store :/ They show the battery percentage too, which is also unavailable with simctl status_bar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to remove the carrier name by passing not an empty string to `operatorName` but a string with just a space `' '`

However, using `operatorName` alone will not have any effect. You also need to activate `cellularMode`.

For Example

```
xcrun simctl status_bar "iPhone 8 Plus" override --operatorName ' '
```

gives this result

[image]

whereas

```
xcrun simctl status_bar "iPhone 8 Plus" override --operatorName ' ' --cellularMode active
```

results in this

[image]

Comment: It didn't work for me (in fact no combination of values for `--operatorName` has had any effect in the release version of Xcode). I've filed a bug with Apple and will keep the question updated with any responses.

Comment: Confirmed, specifying `--cellularBars` (instead of `--cellularMode`) also works. If you want to remove the carrier name, you can make the gap smaller than a space by using a zero-width space: ```--operatorName `echo -ne "\u200B"` ```

Comment: Didn't work for me, Only wifi logo disappeared and nothing changed